# Transfer ownership of boost::asio::socket stack variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a simple tcp socket server capable of handling multiple concurrent connections. The idea is that the main listening thread will do a blocking accept and offload socket handles to a worker thread (in a thread pool) to handle the communication asynchronously from there.

```
void server::run() {
  {
    io_service::work work(io_service);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < pool_size; i++)
      thread_pool.push_back(std::thread([&] { io_service.run(); }));

    boost::asio::io_service listener;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(listener, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), port));

    while (listening) {
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(listener);
      acceptor.accept(socket);
      io_service.post([&] {callback(std::move(socket));});
    }
  }

  for (ThreadPool::iterator it = thread_pool.begin(); it != thread_pool.end(); it++)
    it->join();
}
```

I'm creating `socket` on the stack because I don't want to have to repeatedly allocate memory inside the `while(listening)` loop.

The callback function `callback` has the following prototype:

```
void callback(boost::asio::socket socket);
```

It is my understanding that calling `callback(std::move(socket))` will transfer ownership of `socket` to `callback`. However when I attempt to call `socket.receive()` from inside `callback`, I get a `Bad file descriptor` error, so I assume something is wrong here.

How can I transfer ownership of `socket` to the callback function, ideally without having to create sockets on the heap?

Comment: The bug is that your lambda may be invoked after the loop iteration ends. That means that `socket` will have gone out of scope and calling `std::move()` on a reference to it is undefined.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this safely without allocating space for the socket. The reason is that `io_service::post()` [copies the handler as required](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html). You could probably do it *unsafely* by making your handler a class and defining the copy constructor to move the socket, but note that this violates the semantics of copying. Why are you so reluctant to allocate on the heap - time or space? In either case, the allocation seems likely to be negligible given that you are creating and accepting a socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined behavior is potentially being invoked, as the lambda may be invoking `std::move()` on a previously destroyed socket via a dangling reference.  For example, consider the case where the loop containing the socket ends its current iteration, causing `socket` to be destroyed, before the lambda is invoked:

```
 Main Thread                       | Thread Pool
-----------------------------------+----------------------------------
tcp::socket socket(...);           |
acceptor.accept(socket);           |
io_service.post([&socket] {...});  |
~socket(); // end iteration        |
... // next iteration              | callback(std::move(socket));
```

To resolve this, one needs to transfer `socket` ownership to the handler rather than transfer ownership within the handler.  Per documentation, [Handlers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html) must be `CopyConstructible`, and hence their arguments, including the non-copyable   [`socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket.html), must be as well.  Yet, this requirement can be relaxed if Asio can eliminate all calls to the handler's copy constructor and one has defined `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS`.

```cpp
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void callback(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket);

...

// Transfer ownership of socket to the handler.
io_service.post(
  [socket=std::move(socket)]() mutable
  {
    // Transfer ownership of socket to `callback`.
    callback(std::move(socket));
  });
```

For more details on Asio's type checking, see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4a07770832e543d) answer.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72b53ab87cb9e4ee) a `socket`'s ownership being transferred to a handler:

```cpp
#include <functional> // std::bind
#include <utility>    // std::move
#include <vector>     // std::vector
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

const auto noop = std::bind([]{});

void callback(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
{
  const std::string actual_message = "hello";
  boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(actual_message));
}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);

  // Connect the sockets.
  client_socket.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), noop);
  {
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(socket);
    // Transfer ownership of socket to the handler.
    assert(socket.is_open()); 
    io_service.post(
      [socket=std::move(socket)]() mutable
      {
        // Transfer ownership of socket to `callback`.
        callback(std::move(socket));
      });
    assert(!socket.is_open()); 
  } // ~socket

  io_service.run();

  // At this point, sockets have been conencted, and `callback`
  // should have written data to `client_socket`.
  std::vector<char> buffer(client_socket.available());
  boost::asio::read(client_socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer));

  // Verify the correct message was read.
  const std::string expected_message = "hello";
  assert(std::equal(
    begin(buffer), end(buffer),
    begin(expected_message), end(expected_message)));
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could put an initializer in a lambda capture.

Comment: @rhashimoto that's c++14